# Separate production for modules in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have developed an app in extjs and this app have many modules in it. It is working fine. But when I make production it generates an app.js file for all modules. But I want separate production for all sub modules.

Example :

App Name : MyApp (path : public/)

Modules :

1. ChildApp1 (path : public/app/)
2. ChildApp2 (path : public/app/)
3. ChildApp3 (path : public/app/)
4. ChildApp4 (path : public/app/)

So, when I run `sencha app build` Command it generates app.js file for all modules. But is there any way where I can generate app.js separately for all modules which will not affect other modules.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using sencha *sencha compile*.
Here is an example from the Sencha's Blog: https://www.sencha.com/blog/top-support-tips-march-2016/